# Plotting a curve on a scatter (linear regression) plot

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I have a the following plot in R:

[image: Plot]

I used the following code to build it:

```
df <- read.csv("C:/temp/df.csv")

df.x <- df$DR
df.y <- df$GB

df.fit = lm(df.y ~ df.x)

plot(df.x,df.y,
     xlab="X",
     ylab="Y",
     xlim=c(1,730),
     ylim=c(2400,5000),
     col="blue",pch=20)

grid(10, 10, lwd = 1)
abline(df.fit, col="red",lw=1,lty=1)
df.pred = predict(df.fit, data.frame(df.x=170+365))
points(y=df.pred, x=535, col="black", pch=18)
df.pred.margin = predict(df.fit, data.frame(df.x=170+365+185))
points(y=df.pred.margin, x=535, col=51, pch=18)
abline(h=df.pred.margin, col=51)
abline(v=535, col=51)
```

How would I plot a curve passing all the way through my data points to the green point?

I want to simulate the kind of curve I'd (possibly) see to get to the green point.

Comment: Your data seems to follow a straight line. Are you wanting to plot an exponential curve?

Comment: @rawr yes. This is about resource management and I want to simulate a exponential growth, so as to reserve a margin.

Comment: Use `nls` to fit the desired data points to an exponential function. Or even something like (pseudocode) `lm(y ~ I(a*exp(b*x))`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've done that, but how do I add the curve to the plot once I'm done?

Comment: Use `lines(newx,newy, color=whatever)`